# How to escape special characters like " in the SQL query in order to avoid Injection

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2010

Using delphi 2010, i am wondering if there someway to escape the following string to make it safe from sql injection attacks :

my string :

```
    SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM registered WHERE email="'+
      email+'" and login_pass="'+password+'"';
```

How to rewrite this string, to make it safer than it is when someone type " in my TEditbox as his email or password !

Comment: Use sql parameters:)

Comment: Please do not put the tag info in the question title. That's what tags are for, and repeating it in the title makes the title longer and harder to read. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use parameters, and let the database drivers handle that stuff.

```
SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM registered WHERE email= :email'+
  ' and login_pass = :password';
SQLQuery1.ParamByName('email').AsString := EMail;
SQLQuery1.ParamByName('password').AsString := Password;
```

Comment: this code doesn't work EDatabase Error ( Operation not supported )

Comment: This code works perfectly fine; I have it in use in tons of code that is run every day. What database are you using? What database components? (BTW, you should always mention the database engine when posting SQL questions, as syntax and functionality is different between them.)

Comment: 0x0005 Operation not supported

Comment: @Rafik: Once again, **what database** are you using, and what components? (I asked in my last comment, if you'll notice.)

Answer (score 0):

the basic replacement of ' with '' should make sure that you won't get injected in textual fields.

As a rule of thumb, make sure all inputs you add to the database are in the pattern you expect them to be.
in the case of email addresses, zip codes and passwords- you can define a simple regex to verify the validity.

keep in mind, that numeric fields can be also injected and should be verified as well.

Answer (score -1):

If for whatever reason you can't use parameters, you can use a function like this:

```
USES SysUtils;

FUNCTION QuotedStr(CONST S : STRING) : STRING;
  BEGIN
    Result:='"'+ReplaceStr(S,'"','""')+'"'
  END;
```

and then

```
SQLQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM registered WHERE email='+
  QuotedStr(email)+' and login_pass='+QuotedStr(password);
```

(this assumes that your database provider uses double quotes to delimit strings with and that two consecutive double quotes in a quoted string is really a single double quote, ie. one double quote).

Comment: -1. This does nothing to prevent SQL injection (or even make it more difficult). Also, `QuotedStr` is already in the RTL (in `SysUtils`).

Comment: Use QuotedStr http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.QuotedStr if your DB uses single quotes (e.g. SQL Server), or AnsiQuotedStr (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.AnsiQuotedStr) for others (or always use AnsiQuotedStr with a variable set to the provider syntax)

Comment: @KenWhite: Just out of curiosity: How does this not prevent SQL injection?

Comment: @KenWhite: I have been trying to answer HeartWare's question. But run around in circles because everything that can be done to a string can be done to the sql sent to the server in a parameterized statement. So how does using parameters prevent sql injection? Is it because with parameters you can only have a single sql statement? So any injection of malicious statements would be rejected? Or if someone where to inject it at the front, the server would barf at trying to replace the parameters because they are probably not in the injected command? What am I missing here?

Comment: @Marjan: Yes, multiple statements are prevented, for one thing. It also prevents bad syntax that can reach the DB and generate errors that reveal info useful to bad people. The subject of SQL injection isn't pertinent here; there are dozens of posts on SO about what it is and how to prevent it. I'd be willing to bet that 99% start with "don't create SQL on the fly; use parameters instead". HeartWare, your answer is exactly the same as the original query in the risk for SQL injection; it's dynamic SQL using direct string concatenation that can allow malicious values to reach the database.

Comment: @KenWhite: I can't see how it can allow malicious values to reach the database. I'm not trying to be difficult, but trying to learn something - can you give an example of how a malicious value can reach the database using the QuotedStr approach?

Comment: Given the query `TestQry := 'SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE User = '', and output being `Output := TestQry + MyQuotedStr(Memo1.Text);` (MyQuotedStr is simply yours with two letters prepended), try things in the memo like `"";DELETE * FROM foo;SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user = "JONES"`.

Comment: Typo in my last comment - remove the obvious syntax error (`*'` in DELETE statement).

Comment: That is not a valid example, as my code would be <TestQry:='SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE User='+QuotedStr(Memo1.Text);> (minus angle brackets) and this would result in the SQL statement <SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE User=""""";DELETE * FROM foo;SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user = ""JONES"""> (minus the angle brackets) which wouldn't do anything bad. It would merely search for a user named <"";DELETE * FROM foo;SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user = "JONES"> (without the angle brackets).

Comment: @HeartWare,I'm with you, people tend to over-engineer and use wrapper when the actual solution is super simple. If the expected input is a string, escaping the quotes will prevent sql injection !